# File Upload with some information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, kendo-ui

I am uploading an images for that I created template to display it before upload. Here is code for it:

```
   <script id="fileTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div class='file-wrapper'>
        <h4 class='file-heading file-name-heading'>Name: #=name#</h4>
        <h4 class='file-heading file-description-heading'>Image Heading: <input type="text" id="headingTextbox"/></h4>
    </div>
</script>
```

As you can see I am showing image name in #=name# parameter and I want some information about image therefore I am using Textbox (id: headingTextbox). Now here is my code to upload the images:

```
            $("#files").kendoUpload({
            multiple: true,
            async: {
                saveUrl: "SaveSectionImages",
            },
            upload: function (e) {
                e.data = {
                    hdId: $('#hdId').val(),
                    fileDesc: $('#headingTextbox').val()
                };

            },
            complete: onComplete,
            template: kendo.template($('#fileTemplate').html())
        });
```

Now my problem is if I select multiple images and I get information about only one image then header information is automatically get attached to all images (Because I am using same textbox id for all images). I want pathway that how can I achieve image upload with some information with it?
Any help would be appreciable. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
$("#files").kendoUpload({
      multiple: true,
      async: {
          saveUrl: "SaveSectionImages",
          autoUpload : false
      },
      complete: function(e) {
         var fileList = $("#files").data("kendoUpload").options.files;
         $.each(fileList, function(idx) {    
           this.fileDesc = $('.headingTextbox')[idx].value;
         });
         console.log($("#files").data("kendoUpload").options.files);
      },
      template: kendo.template($('#fileTemplate').html())
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="fileTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div class='file-wrapper'>
        <h4 class='file-heading file-name-heading'>Name: #=name#</h4>
        <h4 class='file-heading file-description-heading'>Image Heading: <input type="text" class="headingTextbox"/></h4>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Image does not get Uploaded